# Adding mesh collider via script to game object and all its child game objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

looking for some help with adding mesh colliders in Unity via script. For example, I want to select GameObject and have script add mesh colliders to each other child gameobject, with exception of said gameobject of having Mesh Filter.

Any help would be appreciated. I'd like to be able to use the script in Editor mode, so I don't have to manually select gameobjects and set colliders to them.

I'm not really too sure how to go about that at the moment.

```
public GameObject object4col;

public void AddMeshColliders(){

    if (object4col.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() == null)
    {
        object4col.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit vague for me to understand but I'll try to answer as per my capabilities.

make a list of the Objects and Use foreach loop with your condition that might help. And to use it in the editor make the Method Static and "Execute in edit mode"

Comment: if those children do no have a `MeshFilter` ... then exactly what mesh should the `MeshCollider` use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through recursively of child objects and add the component.
You can add the method to the context menu, so when you right click on the script's header or click on the three dots on the header's right side, the option will be there.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _target;

[ContextMenu("Add MeshColliders")]
private void AddMeshColliders()
{
    if (_target == null) _target = transform;
    AddRecursively(_target);
}

private void AddRecursively(Transform parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; i++)
    {
        Transform child = parent.GetChild(i);
        if (child.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() != null) child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

        AddRecursively(child);
    }
}
```

Instead of `ContextMenu`, you can write an Editor script, add a button for it and move the whole logic there.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done this way: Import `Linq`

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Select all the child objects of `parentObj` (say) that do not have a mesh collider

```cs
public Transform[] object4cols = parentObj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Where(x => x.GetComponent<MeshCollider>() == null).ToArray();
```

Iterate over the child objects and add a mesh collider to them

```cs
foreach(Transform object4col in object4cols) {
    object4col.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
}
```